# Firefox v6+ plugin to play Windows Media streams?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I am trying to play an audio stream from the web that requires a Windows Media plugin for Firefox. I have had trouble finding a suitable plugin.

I am running FF v6.02

I have tried installing [the mplayer plugin](http://mplayerplug-in.sourceforge.net/index.php), but it's far out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `gecko-mediaplayer` plugin. But in order to install gecko you must first install `gnome-mplayer`.

1. Make sure that you have the Universe and Multiverse repositories enabled. You can do this by opening Synaptic and clicking "Settings" > "Repositories"
2. Install `gnome-mplayer`
3. Install `gecko-mediaplayer`

In Firefox, navigate to Add-Ons and the plugin you need will say "Windows Media Player Plug-in". Make sure it is enabled. You should now be able to play Windows Media streams.

Comment: Post a link, I'll add them for you.